# Fetching products with swatches in product page Shopify

Tags: shopify

[image: 1]

Above is the image.

I'm fetching products in Product page Shopify but the variation swatches not working properly. I used Smart Filter App in Shopify and the products are coming with swatches using GLO Color Swatches. Both are Globo Teams apps. But the variation  swatches not working properly. Suppose we select variation of first product, the other product variations are affected too. I contacted Globo team for that issue but they told me that "It is not possible to change the app workflow as product page has only one product.". Also the wishlist app isn't working while we change variation. It always adds first variation of product.

Anyone has any idea about this issue? Thanks for any suggestions too.

The main goal is Product page contains more from this collection products they can also buy from this collection in Product page. Suppose we have Cloths collection and we opened one product's product page in Shopify. The product page contains More from Cloths collection in which there are many products with variation with add to cart and wishlist. Swatches should work properly with instock or out of stock functionality. Wishlist should perfectly work with variation swatches. If I select Black / Tshirt. The Wishlist must add Black / Tshirt in wishlist not the first variant of products.

Comment: Regarding broken app functionality, you should contact app support. This is what you pay for in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by any app. The only way to do it by custom coding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).